# EDI X12 file validation error (Azure Logic Apps)

Tags: azure, validation

I am trying to validate and parse an X12 file (835/837) in Microsoft Azure using Logic Apps. I have setup my integrations account, tied it to the logic app, schema and agreement is done.

However I get the following error:

> {
>     "errorMessage": "Error: 1 (Miscellaneous error)\r\n\t522: Delimiters are not unique, field and segment separator are the same\r\n\r\n",
>     "statusCode": "BadRequest"
>   }

I was told by Microsoft it is an EDI file validation error. Where do I even begin to look to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this was due to my having multiple charges and items in an X12 210 file, but like tags, with the same parent, weren't grouped together.

Solution was achieved by having the XML being validated's tags rearranged from something like:

```
<L5>
   <L501>1</L501>
   <L502>Something</L502>
</L5>
<L1>
   <L101>1</L101>
   <L102>2</L102>
   <L103>3</L103>
   <L104>4</L104>
   <L108>5</L108>
</L1>
<L5>
   <L501>2</L501>
   <L502>Something Else</L502>
</L5>
<L1>
   <L101>6</L101>
   <L102>7</L102>
   <L103>8</L103>
   <L104>9</L104>
   <L108>0</L108>
</L1>
```

To

```
<L5>
   <L501>1</L501>
   <L502>Something</L502>
</L5>
<L5>
   <L501>2</L501>
   <L502>Something Else</L502>
</L5>
<L1>
   <L101>1</L101>
   <L102>2</L102>
   <L103>3</L103>
   <L104>4</L104>
   <L108>5</L108>
</L1>
<L1>
   <L101>6</L101>
   <L102>7</L102>
   <L103>8</L103>
   <L104>9</L104>
   <L108>0</L108>
</L1>
```

**Note the sequential grouping of same tags on the same level.**

My tip-off occurred looking through the schema and discovering an element's attribute, **structure="delimited"**

```
<xs:element name="X12_00401_210">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:recordInfo **structure="delimited"** field_order="postfix" delimiter_type="inherit_record" count_ignore="yes" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" notes="Motor Carrier Freight Details and Invoice" />
      </xs:appinfo>
enter code here
      ...
```

Unfortunately, I can't find a resource that confirms my suspicion, though [this BizTalk Microsoft Docs link's](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/technical-reference/record-node-properties) wording of "positional or delimited" lead me to believe tags might need to be linked together, with a specified delimited structure. It's an admitted cognitive leap.

Hopefully this helps.